# Royalty Free Anime characters

Tags: royalty-free

I'm trying to find an online resource for royalty free anime characters, but i'm having an issue finding anything of a reasonable quality.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: If this is the wrong place, or inappropriate for stack  exchange please let me know.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show us the style of anime you like (if you can post a picture)? Also, do you need this in vector? Finally, by "quality", do you mean more details on the artwork? If you have a precise idea of what you want, there's always inexpensive illustrators that you can hire for your project on freelance's sites; and lot of non-professional illustrators do anime style too.

Comment: also please specify if you're looking for sprites or regular images etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great forum page on Steam with resources for Visual Novels [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/345370/discussions/0/611701360822466443/). Scroll down to where it offers characters.

OpenGameArt.Org has a bunch of resources too, find them [here](http://opengameart.org/art-search?keys=anime).

Also The Jaded Network, [here](http://thejadednetwork.com/gallery/anime/).

Wpclipart.com has a small collection of anime stuff [here](http://www.wpclipart.com/cartoon/anime/). I'm not always sure how well they are sourced though and the quality varies.